# Will the club finishing 4th in the EPL go to any European competition if clubs from 5 to 8 win corresponding titles granting European qualification?

Tags: rules, football, uefa, champions-league, europa-league

Starting the 2018/19 season there will be a [new distribution rules](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2398611.html#/) in the Champions League (CL) and Europa League (EL). CL and EL winners will get automatic spot in group stages.

The new rule states that no country can have more than 5 teams in CL. I am wondering what will be the outcome for the following case in England:

1) CL and EL winners are both from England and finish 5th and 6th in EPL.

2) FA Cup and League Cup winners finish, let's say 7th and 8th in the EPL.

In that case, will the club finishing 4th in the EPL go to any European competition?

Comment: The title holders go first, so the club ranked 4th would drop out of the CL and play EL instead.. When I find a credible source I'll turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regulations of the UEFA Champions League 2018-21 Cycle:

> https://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/55/82/79/2558279_DOWNLOAD.pdf

1) If UEFA Champions League and UEFA Europa League title holders are both from England and they both finish outside of the top four in Premier League, then the 4th placed Premier League team will not qualify for a place in the UEFA Champions League, but instead qualify for a place in the UEFA Europa League.

> Ref to 3.07 a.

2) The 4th placed Premier League team is always guaranteed a place in either the UEFA Champions League or the UEFA Europa League.

> Ref to 3.07 a, b, c.

Other sources:

> https://www.thesun.co.uk/sport/football/3097329/champions-league-english-teams-fourth-place-premier-league/)